# How To split a string in c# and keep the delimiter in the array while excluding white space in a name parser

Tags: regex, string, split, delimiter

This took me a while to figure out so I will Post my results here in the Question as this is Answered.

Question: How do i split a string using a array of possible delimiters in a name field while keeping the delimiter in the split array and excluding white-space the split may create in the array.

Example: Sam Washington& Jenna

My issue was the name parser i created was writing

Firstname:Sam

LastName : Jenna

Answer (score 1):

Using the following code I was able to Parse it out like this

FirstName: Sam

Lastname : Washington

Firstname2 Jenna

Be careful However because if you are going to use my list of joiners do not include string values that can be found in common names such as "And" and "OR"

This would parse your names EX: "Andy" would be "And" , "Y"

EX2: "Gregory would be "Greg" "or" "y"

Hope this helps someone. If you have questions please feel free to shoot me a message.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// remove bad name parts
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="parts">name parsed for review</param>
    public static void CheckBadNames(ref string[] parts)
    {
        string[] BadName = new string[] {"LIFE", "ESTATE" ,"(",")","*","AN","LIFETIME","INTREST","MARRIED",
                                         "UNMARRIED","MARRIED/UNMARRIED","SINGLE","W/","/W","THE","ET",
                                         "ALS","AS", "TENANT","WIFE", "HUSBAND", "NOT", "DRIVE" ,"INSURED",                 
                                         "EXCLUDED","DISABLED" ,"LICENSED","TRUSTEE","ATSOT","A T S O T",
                                         "AKA", "-ATSOT","OF","DBA","EVOCABLE","FAMILY","INTEREST","MASTER"};
        string[] joiners = new string[9] { "&", @"AND\", @"OR\", "\\", "&/OR", "AND/OR", "&-OR", "/", "OF/AND" };

    Restart:
        List<string> list = new List<string>(parts); //convert array to list
        foreach (string part in list)
        {
            if (BadName.Any(s => part.ToUpper().Equals(s)) || part == "-")
            {
                list.Remove(part);
                parts = list.ToArray();
                goto Restart;
            }
            //check to see if any part ends with joiner
            if (joiners.Any(s => part.ToUpper().EndsWith(s)))
            {
                //check if by ends with means that it is just a joiner
                if (joiners.Any(s => part.ToUpper().Equals(s)))
                {
                    continue;
                }
                else //name part ends with a joiner EX. Washington&
                {
                    foreach (string div in joiners.Where(s => part.ToUpper().Contains(s)))  // each string that contains a joiner
                    {
                        var temp = Regex.Split(part, "(" + div + ")").Where(x => x != String.Empty); // split into parts ignore leading or trailing spaces
                        int pos = list.IndexOf(part);
                        list.Remove(part);

                        for (int i = 0; i < temp.Count(); i++)
                        {
                            list.Insert(pos + i, temp.ElementAt(i));
                        }
                        parts = list.ToArray();
                        goto Restart;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (parts.Count() == 0)
        {
            return;
        }
        if (joiners.Any(s => list.Last().ToUpper().Equals(s))) //remove last part if is a joiner
        {
            list.Remove(list.Last());
        }

        parts = list.ToArray(); // convert list back to array
    }
```

Comment: Are you really using goto? :O

Comment: yes I am. It is the easiest way to restart a process or exit out of nested loops and if statements.